# How to display ngx-timepicker-field timepicker next to a div , instead of showing it as a pop up

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, timepicker

I want to display a time picker in my application in which either user can enter the time manually or pick it from a time picker.

And for this, I am using the **ngx-timepicker-field** and it works perfectly fine.

The issue is instead of showing the time picker pop up in the middle of the page is there any option available to show it near to the input filed or a div. similar to appends to input option available for **ngx-material-timepicker**

Reference link: https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks